# Open Source image editor that handles PNG Alpha transparency correctly?

Tags: open-source, png, transparency, image-editing

I want to be able to take a sample image, and be able to fade out the background.

For example, I might take a picture of a bird.
Make most of the background almost completely transparent, and have a smooth transition to full opacity adjacent to the subject.

Most of all, I want to be able to save / export to PNG.

Comment: Which operating systems should it run on?

Comment: I would like to be able to run on Linux. I specifically didn't specify an operating system, because I wanted this to be as useful as possible, to everybody.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) should be able to do what you want. It's free and open source.

Answer (score 11):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) if you're on Windows. IMO, a lot easier to deal with than The GIMP, if you're already slightly familiar with Photoshop.

Comment: This was never open source, just freeware with source available. Rick decided to close the source access so it is now a binary only distribution. Now what is interesting is the license talks about source code so technically you could beat some drums and get the source code and require a license change!

Comment: I suspect the poster was primarily concerned about the Free Software aspect typically associated with Open Source... ;)

Comment: Free is nice. Open Source is better.

Answer (score 1):

[Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) is a great application.  However, the learning curve is pretty steep.  I have not figured out how to do a simple color replacement or transparency with it yet.  The easiest program I have ever used for that is Paint Shop Pro.

After reading about [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) I downloaded it. It beat Gimp Hands Down.  A great program for the Novice.

Comment: Programs easily used by a novice tend to be under-powered when you are no longer a novice. If you don't plan on becoming a expert at it, go ahead and use whatever is easier for you.